# Vga и d-sub

Tags: windows, монитор

Подскажите, vga и d-sub - это одно и то же?

Comment: Не совсем. Есть как минимум 5 видов D-Sub и вот (D15 или D15HD) = VGA, а вообще описание есть [ТУТ][1]


  [1]: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В бытовом смысле -- да.

А вообще -- [d-sub](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-sub) это семейство разъемов, d-sub разъем DE15 используется для подключения монитора по интерфейсу [VGA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA).

Термин VGA также используется для обозначения 15-контактного разъёма VGA для передачи аналоговых видеосигналов при различных разрешениях.